# Arduino (C++) sketc periodically freezes or resets: suspected overflow

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm having trouble identifying the cause of a recurrent issue with some arduino code. The code below reads two temperature sensors, sends the result to a PID library, and uses the output to control some relays on a fridge (adding accurate temperature control to a fridge, basically).

The code freezes or the Arduino resets periodically. This happens periodically, but the period changes - it freezes every minimum 30 minutes, maximum about 30 hours.

I suspect that there's an overflow or that I'm writing beyond the range of an array, but I can't find the issue. It's very unlikely that there's a power issue - the arduino is on a 10A 12v supply with a dedicated 5v regulator, so I doubt it.

I'm fairly new to all this and would be very grateful for any pointers or advice - even some tips on how to troubleshoot this unpredictable error would be very appreciated!

Here's the code:

Setup and main loop, also checks an analog input for the set temperature:

```
// Call libraries for display, sensor, I2C, and memory. Library setup included as well.
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
char buffer[20];

#include <Time.h>
#include <TimeLib.h>
#include <OneWire.h> 
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x3f,20,4); 
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#include <PID_v1.h>

// Special Characters for the display and display animations
#if defined(ARDUINO) && ARDUINO >= 100
#define printByte(args)  write(args);
#else
#define printByte(args)  print(args,BYTE);
#endif
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 5  //DS18S20 Signal pin on digital 2
uint8_t heart[8] = { 0x0,0xa,0x1f,0x1f,0xe,0x4,0x0};
uint8_t deg[8] = { 0x1c,0x14,0x1c,0x0,0x3,0x4,0x4,0x3};
uint8_t Pv[8] = { 0x1c,0x14,0x1c,0x10,0x10,0x5,0x5,0x2};
uint8_t Sv[8] = { 0xc,0x10,0x8,0x4,0x18,0x5,0x5,0x2};
// end special chars 


//************* Begin Variables Setup ***************//

//Sensors (ds18s20 needs additional chatter)

  byte addr1[8]= {0x28, 0x3F, 0xB5, 0x3C, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x25};
  byte addr2[8]= {0x28, 0xC7, 0xCD, 0x4C, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0D};
  byte data1[12];
  byte data2[12];
  byte MSB = 0;
  byte LSB = 0; 
  float tempRead = 0;
  float TemperatureSum = 0;
  OneWire ds(ONE_WIRE_BUS);
  OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS); 
  DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);


//controller outputs
int ControlCpin = 6; // control to fridge
int ControlTpin = 8; // control to temperature/heater  (get aquarium heater)
int ControlLpin = 7; // control to light
int ControlApin = 9; // control to airflow

//operational vars (the button)
//int buttonPushCounter = 0;   // counter for the number of button presses DEPRACATED
int buttonState = 0;         // current state of the button
int lastButtonState = 0;     // previous state of the button
boolean buttonstate = false; // calculastate of the button (includes timer delay. use this in menus)
int buttontime = 0;          // press length measure 
int buttontimeon = 0;        // necessary for press length measure 

//operational vars (sensors and timing)
unsigned int sensorInterval = 20000;         // time between readings
unsigned long int sensorTime = 0;           // current time 
unsigned long int sensorTime2 = 0;          // time of last sensor reading

// fans, lights, and timers
unsigned long int fanONmillis = 0;
unsigned long int fanOFFmillis = 0;
byte fanON = 0;
byte fanOFF = 0;
boolean fanstate = false;
unsigned long int Time = 0;
unsigned long int TimeAdjust = 0;

unsigned long int LightON = 0;
unsigned long int LightOFF = 0;
unsigned int Hours = 0;
unsigned int Minutes = 0;
unsigned int Days = 0;
byte daysAdj = 0; //not implemented yet
float tempDiff = 0;

//key var storage
float PvH = 0; 
double PvT = 0;
float SvH = 0; 
double SvT = 12; 
float SvTdisplay = 5.5;
float SvTdisplayOld = 5.5;

float Temp1;                   //Current readings
float Temp2;                   //Current readings
float Temp3;                   //Current readings

// Fridge limits
unsigned int safetyRest = 5; // off this long every hour (minimum) to let the compressor rest in minutes
int minCool = 10; // minimum cooling period in minutes
int coolStart = 0;
byte coolON = 0;  // PID attached to this

// Heat limits
byte heatON = 0;  // PID attached to this

//cool
double Kp = 0.5;
double Ki = 0.5;
double Kd = 0.5;
double Output;
PID coolPID(&PvT, &Output, &SvT ,Kp,Ki,Kd, REVERSE);
unsigned coolWindowSize = 600;  // minutes*10
unsigned long coolWindowStartTime;
unsigned long coolOffElapsed = 0;
long unsigned PIDpos = 0; 

  unsigned long Outputx = 0;
  unsigned long PIDposx = 0;
  unsigned long safetyRestx = 0;

// ensure setpoint, input, and outpit are defined

//************* End Variables Setup ***************//


void setup(){

//Sensor start

  sensors.begin();


//Pin declarations  
  pinMode(ControlTpin, OUTPUT); //set outputs
  pinMode(ControlLpin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ControlApin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ControlCpin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ControlTpin, HIGH); // write outputs HIGH (off in this case) FIRST to prevent startup jitters.
  digitalWrite(ControlLpin, HIGH); 
  digitalWrite(ControlApin, HIGH); 
  digitalWrite(ControlCpin, HIGH); 

//LCD and special chars
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin();                      
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.createChar(0, heart);
  lcd.createChar(1, deg);
  lcd.createChar(2, Pv);
  lcd.createChar(3, Sv);
  lcd.clear();
  LoadScreen();
  HomeSetup();
  //PID setup
  coolPID.SetOutputLimits(0, coolWindowSize);
  coolPID.SetMode(AUTOMATIC);
  coolOffElapsed = millis();
}

void loop(){
  //if interval has passed, check the sensors, update the triggers, and update the screen
  if (millis() - sensorTime2 > sensorInterval){ 
     sensorTime2 = millis();
     SensorCheck();
     Triggers();
     HomeSetup ();
  }

  SvTdisplay = (float)analogRead(A0);
  SvTdisplay = SvTdisplay/40+5;
  if(abs(SvTdisplay-SvTdisplayOld) > 0.2){
    SvTdisplayOld = SvTdisplay;
    lcd.setCursor(2,0);
    lcd.print(SvTdisplayOld,1);     //svt
    lcd.printByte(1);
    lcd.print(" ");
    SvT = analogRead(A0)/4+50;
    }
  PIDpos = ((millis()/60000) % (coolWindowSize/10));
 }
```

The following codes a loading screen and updates the screen with current values:

```
void LoadScreen (){
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.home();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print(" LaggerLogger "); 
  lcd.printByte(0);
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print(" V2.0 Beepboop!"); 
  delay(3000);
  lcd.clear();
 }

//write the home screen to the LCD with current data 

void HomeSetup(){
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.printByte(3);
  lcd.print(" ");
  lcd.print(SvTdisplayOld,1);     //svt
  lcd.printByte(1);
  lcd.print(" ");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.printByte(2);
  lcd.print(" "); 
  lcd.print(PvT/10,1);   //pvt
  lcd.printByte(1);
  lcd.print(" ");
  lcd.setCursor(8,1);
  lcd.print(day()-1);
  lcd.print("/");
  lcd.print(hour());
  lcd.print(":");
  lcd.print(minute());
  lcd.print(" ");
  lcd.setCursor(8,0);
  lcd.print(Output/10,1);
  lcd.print("m/h ");    
}
```

The following checks output values and 'triggers' the relay if its appropriate to do so:

```
void Triggers () {
  coolPID.Compute();

  // Check PID
  if ((Output/10) > (coolWindowSize/10-PIDpos) && PIDpos > safetyRest ) {  //
    coolON = 1;
    coolStart = millis();
  }
  else if ((millis() - coolStart) > (minCool * 60000)){
    coolON = 0;
  }
  else {}

  // Write to temp relay pins
  if (coolON == 1) {
    digitalWrite(ControlCpin, LOW);
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(ControlCpin, HIGH);
  }

  // Control fans
  if (coolON == 1 || heatON == 1 || tempDiff > 1) {
    fanOFFmillis = millis();
    fanONmillis = millis();
    fanstate = true;
    digitalWrite(ControlApin, LOW);
  }
  else {
    fanstate = false;
    digitalWrite(ControlApin, HIGH);
  }
}
```

The following checks the temperature sensors and does some clock calculations:

```
void SensorCheck(){ 

     Temp1 = getTemp1();
     Temp2 = getTemp2();

    //average readings and note the difference
    if(Temp1 > 0 && Temp2 >0) { 
      PvT = (Temp1 + Temp2) / .2;
      tempDiff = abs(Temp1 - Temp2);
    }

    //... unless there's only one thermometer...
    else if (Temp1 > 0){  
      PvT = Temp1*10;
      tempDiff = 0;
    }
    else {
      PvT = 999;
      tempDiff = 0;
    }

    //clock update
    Time = millis() + TimeAdjust;
    Hours = hour();
    Minutes = minute();
    Days = day();  
}

float getTemp1(){
 sensors.requestTemperatures();
 float z = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);
 return z;
 }

float getTemp2(){
 sensors.requestTemperatures();
 float z = sensors.getTempCByIndex(1);
 return z;
}
```

Comment: My suggestion is that you [find a simpler problem](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/). I don't know how good the debugging tools are for Arduino, but try to simplify your program, remove parts of it until it works again. Then you add back the non-working part, and continue removing all other parts. The less code you have, the easier it will be to figure out what might be wrong with it, and the easier it will be to fix it.

Comment: Also, in line with my above comment, never try to add do much at once. Add a small piece of code, and test it out before continuing and adding the next piece. That way it's easier to find errors in the narrow piece of code you written, and easier to fix without affecting to much of everything else.

Comment: Lastly, in the future be careful with your tags, so you don't add the wrong tags (like `android` for an `arduino` question, like you did).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions S.p dude!

Comment: Comment out Triggers () in loop() to see if the problem is in the PID values. Use some dummy values for checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that an integer (declared as int coolStart) was later updated to hold the value of millis().

Millis() can be much larger than the 16 bits available to ints - creating an overflow.

Changing the variable declaration to 'unsigned long coolStart = 0;' appears to have solved the problem.

Thanks to everyone for the troubleshooting advice.